# Would there be a memory leak if Asynchttpclient is not closed?

Tags: java, netty, asynchttpclient

We are using [AsynHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) in our application. We have a use case where we have to make huge number of fire and forget requests, As this uses NIo we thought its a good approach.

The [AHC Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client#client)  as mentioned in the documentation suggests it shares life cycle as application("AsyncHttpClient instances are intended to be global resources that share the same lifecycle as the application").

So I initialized the AHC client once and kept on using it.

An overview of what the functionality is:

```
public class Client{

  private static AsyncHttpClientConfig asyncHttpClientConfig = new AsyncHttpClientConfig().Builder().setRequestTimeout(someMs).setMaxRetryCount()

  private static AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = AsyncHTTPClientFactory.getAsyncHttpClient(asyncHttpClientConfig)

  public static AsyncHttpClient getClient(){
    return asyncHttpClient;
  }
}

public class Usageclass{

  // some code 
  AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = Client.getClient();
  Future response = asyncHttpClient.setRootEndpoint(url).setBody(body).execute();
}
```

We would be able to monitor the JVM memory available through a dashboard provided by other team. I see that the JVM memory available in the application goes down with incoming requests, as soon as GC(garbage collector) kicks in I see the memory is not completely freed up. Each time garbage collection done the available JVM memory is reduced from previous runs.

I wanted to know if this is because we are not closing the AHC connection ? If so what would be the right approach ?

Comment: I think the problem with network connection.As soon as the network connection closed nested objects that in the asyncHttpClient will be collected. By the way I recommed to usage of Dependency Injection in any Enterprise Java Application.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean